# Do homotopy groups "always" commute with filtered colimits?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

It is well-known that homotopy groups, of, say, simplicial sets, commute with filtered colimits.

However, I could not find a reference for an analogous result for homotopy groups of spectra, or, under which hypothesis the same result would hold for an "arbitrary" simplicial model category.

More precisely, let $\cal{M}$ be a simplicial model category. For a fibrant object $X \in \cal{M}$ its *homotopy groups* with coefficients in a cofibrant object $W\in \cal{M}$ may be defined as

$$
\pi_n (X; W) = [\Sigma^nW, X] = \pi_n \mathrm{map}(W,X) \ ,
$$

where $\mathrm{map} $ denotes the simplicial mapping space from $W$ to $X$.

> So my first question is: which hypothesis do I have to assume for $W$ to obtain an isomorphism
>
> $$
> >\mathrm{colim}_i \pi_n (X_i;W) = \pi_n (\mathrm{colim}_i X_i;W) \   ?
> >$$
>
> And the second one: in which kind of model category such an isomorphism holds  *for every* cofibrant object $W$ -or, at least, for "sufficiently" many cofibrant objects $W$?

The reason behind my question is the following (and explains the meaning of that "sufficiently"): I have a filtered category $I$, functors $X_\bullet, Y_\bullet : I \longrightarrow {\cal M}\_f$ and a natural transformation $f_\bullet : X_\bullet \longrightarrow Y_\bullet$, such that, for every cofibrant object $W$, $f_\bullet$ induces  isomorphisms

$$
\mathrm{colim}_i \pi_n (X_i ; W) = \mathrm{colim}_i \pi_n (Y_i ; W) \ ,
$$

for every $n$. And I want to conclude that the induced map between the colimits

$$
\mathrm{colim}_i X_i \longrightarrow \mathrm{colim}_i Y_i
$$

is a weak equivalence. Which would be true if

1. I could commute colimits and homotopy groups, at least for
2. "enough" cofibrant objects $W$ -in case of simplicial sets, one point $W = *$ is enough.

I suspect the answer involves words like "smallness / compactness" and "cellular model category". For instance an answer like: "You can do that in no matter what simplicial cellular model category" -in which every cofibrant object is compact- would be fine. Nevertheless, as long as I can understand, commutations like

$$
\mathrm{colim}_i {\cal M} (W, X_i ) = {\cal M} (W, \mathrm{colim}_i X_i)
$$

hold for $W$ small and $\lambda$-*sequences*; that is, when the domain of the functor $X : \lambda \longrightarrow \cal{M}$ is an *ordinal*; in particular, a *totally ordered* set, which my filtered $I$ needs not to be.

So any references of a result along these lines, even just for spectra, are welcome.

Answer (score 12):

The condition you're looking for is called combinatoriality (and local presentability).  A model category is combinatorial provided it satisfies some complicated conditions involving accessibility, but at least when the underlying category is a presheaf topos and the cofibrations are exactly the monomorphisms, we can actually systematically construct these model structures using the framework of Denis-Charles Cisinski in his book *Les Préfaisceaux comme modèles des types d'homotopie* (Astérisque 308).  This, in particular gives us the combinatoriality of the model structure on simplicial sets essentially for free.

For a general reference on combinatoriality and Jeff Smith's theorem, I suggest you take a look at the papers *Sheafifiable Homotopy Model Categories* by Tibor Beke and *On Left and Right Model Categories and Left and
Right Bousfield Localizations* by Clark Barwick. (The original theorem is due to Jeff Smith, but he has neglected to publish it (it was announced at a conference and the main ideas were given, I believe), although he has assured us (not me specifically!) many times that he is in the process of publishing a book).

Comment: By the way, combinatoriality is the condition, and Jeff Smith's theorem is the theorem that proves al the nice things about it.

Comment: Regarding spectra, I believe that if you use symmetric spectra à la HSS, you can apply some general theorems to deduce combinatoriality from the combinatoriality of the underlying model category (in this case, it would be "simplicial symmetric sequences").  However, simplicial symmetric sequences have a Cisinski model structure, so we know that they are combinatorial, at least.

Comment: Thanks Harry for pointing me to combinatoriality. Nevertheless I think the problem I talked about "filtered" vs "totally ordered" remains, isn't it? I mean: combinatoriality, again, is a condition about colimits of $\lambda$-sequences, not filtered ones. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Combinatoriality is for filtered stuff, not just ordinal stuff.  Did you read the references I gave you?  For instance, the statement about weak equivalences that you want is proven in the appendix to Jacob Lurie's _Higher Topos Theory_ (I want to say in section 2.6).  

Comment: @Harry. For the moment, I've only read what I could find at the nLab. I'll check Lurie's reference. Thank you very much.

Comment: Rather, appendix 2.6.

Comment: Harry: please, correct me if I'm wrong (which is almost sure the case), but if I understand all this story about cardinals (which is unlikely), the objects of a combinatorial model category are $\lambda$-small... for some big enough cardinal $\lambda$. Right? But being just (finitely) small is stronger than being $\lambda$-small for any other bigger (infinite) cardinal $\lambda$. [to be continued]

Comment: [sequel] Since my index category $I$ is just filtered (finitely filtered) I would need my objects (my cofibrant objects, some of them at least) to be (finitely) small, not "eventually" small for some big enough cardinal. Thus, as far as I understand, "combinatorial" may be not the word in this case, is it?

Comment: Nope, still wrong.  Please read the relevant references. A combinatorial model category is locally presentable (Lurie calls this presentable) hence large.  This is some pretty technical stuff, and you really need to read the definitions before you even try to read the theorems....

Comment: @Harry, the underlying category of symmetric spectra is not precisely "simplicial symmetric sequences" (rather it is modules over the sphere spectrum symmetric sequence).  However, the category of symmetric spectra is locally presentable and the model structures constructed in, e.g. HSS, MMSS, Shipley's "A Convenient ..." paper are all cofibrantly generated, hence combinatorial.

Although the combinatorial condition is the "right" condition for this sort of thing, for spectra, you don't need all this machinery. You might just want section 2 of Hovey-Palmieri-Strickland.

Comment: @Sam: Yes, I realize that it's not the same underlying category, but the idea is similar to how the category of simplicial $A$-modules is combinatorial for any simplicial Commutative Ring $A$. By the way, cofibrant generation absolutely does not imply combinatoriality.  Combinatoriality is strictly stronger (unless you're suggesting that we take Vopenka's principle to be true).  

Comment: Also, I wasn't aware that this was covered in later papers on symmetric spectra.  I'll definitely check them out.  I wonder if they ever came up with a better model structure for them...

Comment: @Harry, combinatorial usually means "locally presentable" and "cofibrantly generated"; did I not make that clear in my comment?  Regarding model structures on symmetric spectra, you might add Schwede's excellent "Untitled book project ..." (found on his website) to a list of references. The abundance of model structures on symmetric spectra is a good thing.

Comment: @Sam: Oh, missed where you mentioned local presentability.  Thanks for the Schwede reference as well.